# jQuery Mobile Site using an ajax $.get() to check username availability returning previous page code in return data

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I have a simple JQM site I'm working on.  I'm trying to validate the availability of a username on the fly in a form.  I'm using jquery $.get() ajax to return "success" or "fail" however the return data is being replace with the code of the previous page.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {

    // check to see if username is available
    $("#username").change(function() {
        $.get("controller.php", { action: "check_username", username: username }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }      
});
```

The controller.php is checking for availability of the username and return "pass" or "fail"  When I do the console.log(data) which I'm expecting to be pass or fail, it's logging out the code from the previous page??

I'm thinking maybe it's a JQM caching issue so I tried to disable cache with no effect.  I was orginally using a JQM dialog box to display the form.  Thinking that had something to do with it I pulled that out and loaded a straight  link.  That didn't fix it so I tried to load the page directly using

`$.mobile.changePage( "user-new.php", { reloadPage: true});`

I am stumped.  Why would a $.get ajax call return data be returning code from the previous page?

Comment: Do you have duplicate `id`? Try removing `pageinit` binding and replace `.change` with `.on('change', function`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a face palm!  My controller was authenticating and kicking it back out to a login page.  Apparently php redirects act funky with ajax return data.  Rather then returning the login page code it was returning the previous page code.  I Removed the authentication and it works fine.  Unbelievable!  I'm going to go work at a gas station or something :)